# Bloqueo App al pulsar sobre TextField- Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

estoy realizando un cambio en la app de Iphone y de repente me he encontrado que al pulsar sobre los Textfield se bloquea la App. Esto antes no pasaba. Ni tampoco da ningun error cuando ocurre. La verdad que es algo que no me habia pasado nunca.

El unico textfield que me funciona es el de la password y los otros si les pongo lo mismo deja introducir algo en ellos.

Sabeis porque puede ser?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, haz el [tour] y lee [ask]; necesitamos un [repro] de lo que tienes hasta el momento para poder ayudarte

Comment: seria bueno q compartas código.

Comment: Utilizas algún pod? Sigue las recomendaciones para poder ayudarte.